# one to many object relationship

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, discord.js

hi i have one array of objects trying to make a chat-bot using discord so one input give me more than output under certain circumstances but i'm struggling , here is my array

```
let message = [{
        "message": "hi",
        "reply": "1-order 2-inquiry 3-complain"
    },

    {
        "message": "1",
        "reply": "please clarify your address"
    },

    {
        "message": "2",
        "reply": "about 1-delivery time 2-delivery fees",
        "response": {
            "1": "from 8 am to 11 pm",
            "2": "10$"
        }
    },

    {
        "message": "3",
        "reply": "1-expired products 2-other",
        "response": {
            "1": "please clarify the product name ",
            "2": "please leave a comment"
        }
    }
]
```

the question here how can i specify that when i enter 1 the chat-bot will respond with that specific reply that means one input has many outputs so how can i make this

many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.find` which returns the first item in an array that matches with our condition.
We can implement it like this

```
const input = '1'; // we assume the input was '1'

const output = message.find(q => {
    return (q.message === input);
});

console.log(output.reply);
```

Here, try it

```js
let message = [
  {
    "message": "hi",
    "reply": "1-order 2-inquiry 3-complain"
  },

  {
    "message": "1",
    "reply": "please clarify your address"
  },

  {
    "message": "2",
    "reply": "about 1-delivery time 2-delivery fees",
    "response": {
        "1": "from 8 am to 11 pm",
        "2": "10$"
    }
  },

  {
    "message": "3",
    "reply": "1-expired products 2-other",
    "response": {
        "1": "please clarify the product name ",
        "2": "please leave a comment"
    }
  }
];

const input = '1'; // we assume the input was '1'

const output = message.find(q => {
    return (q.message === input);
});

console.log(output.reply);
```